# Hibernate Search Circular reference

Tags: facebook, hibernate

I am using hibernate search. I have following  User  class and I use Hibernate Self Join Annotations One To Many mapping

**This is my POJO:**

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
@Indexed
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private Integer id;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String userName;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String email;
private String password;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String gender;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private Date joinDate;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private Date cancellationDate;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String address;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String cellPhone;
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private Boolean enabled;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
private AppRole appRole;

@IndexedEmbedded
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id")
private User vendor;
@ContainedIn
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "vendor")
private Set<User> customers = new HashSet<User>();


}
```

**I got the following Problem:**

```
    org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Circular reference. Duplicate use of com.pericent.dms.data.User in root entity com.pericent.dms.data.User#vendor.
```

How can I resolve above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and found an answer here:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=991727&view=previous

You need to set a depth on the vendor annotation, like this:

```
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
```

Otherwise the Indexer complains about a potentially never-ending chain of references.

The depth you set will limit how far you can search along the relation, e.g. with a depth of 1 you can query for vendor.email, but asking for vendor.vendor.email would require a depth of 2.

Also, you should annotate the id with

```
@DocumentId
```

and not as a field - see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Hibernate_Search_Reference_Guide/Hibernate_Search-Mapping.html#Hibernate_Search-Entity-Basic_Mapping